# How to organize common code in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

I have a Scala program that has several classes with a lot of common code.  A lot of the code is generic so you have things like this (using TypeTags to keep the type info):

```
object ModelA {

    def update(id: UUID, changes: Map[String, Any]) = {
        Validate.partialInstanceOf[ModelA](changes) match {
            ...
        }
    }

}
```

and ...

```
object ModelB {

    def update(id: UUID, changes: Map[String, Any]) = {
        Validate.partialInstanceOf[ModelB](changes) match {
            ...
        }
    }

}
```

I've fairly new to Scala, so I was wondering what was the best way to DRYify this code.  I see two possibilities: trait or helper class.  This is what I had in mind for the trait:

```
trait Model[M <: Model] {
    def update(id: UUID, changes: Map[String, Any]) = {
        Validate.partialInstanceOf[M](changes) match {
            ...
        }
    }
}

object ModelA extends Model[ModelA]
object ModelB extends Model[ModelB]
```

... and this is what I had in mind for the helper class:

```
object ModelHelper {
    def update[M](id: UUID, changes: Map[String, Any]) = {
        Validate.partialInstanceOf[M](changes) match {
            ...
        }
    }
}

object ModelA {

    def update(id: UUID, changes: Map[String, Any]) = {
        ModelHelper.update[ModelA](id, changes);
    }

}
...
```

My question is: What is a more idiomatic Scala approach? Passing a child type to a parent trait seems kind of icky to me. Is this OK to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more idiomatic to use the trait, as it's DRYer.  The Scala library does it all over the place, e.g.:

```
object ArrayBuffer extends SeqFactory[ArrayBuffer] ...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are likely to want to mix in multiple traits providing different aspects of functionality, all of which need to know what specific type they are working with, you might want to consider a pattern such as the following:

```
trait Updatable {
    type M
    def update(id: UUID, changes: Map[String, Any]) = {
        Validate.partialInstanceOf[M](changes) match {
            ...
        }
    }
}

trait Jsonable {
    type M
    def toJson(model: M) = {
        ...
    }
}

... other functionality traits ...

object ModelA extends Updatable with Jsonable with ... { type M = ModelA.type }
object ModelB extends Updatable with Jsonable with ... { type M = ModelB.type }
class ModelC extends Updatable with Jsonable with ... { type M = ModelC } // Example for class types rather than objects, if that is relevant.
```

You can then test each trait's function independently, and don't have to start writing things like `object ModelD extends Updatable[ModelD] with Jsonable[ModelD] with ...`